# Drag and drop with Antd's Tree table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, antd, react-dnd

I am trying to make a tree table reorderable via drag and drop.

Here's the render for easier visualization:

[image]

I am also using [React-DnD](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/api/hooks-overview).

Here's a piece of my code:

```
const moveRow = useCallback(
  (record: StructureElement) => (dragIndex, hoverIndex) => {
    // console.log(record.name, dragIndex, hoverIndex);
    const dragRow = sortableData[dragIndex];
    if (!dragRow) {
      console.log(sortableData, dragIndex);
    } else {
      console.log('drag', dragRow.name, 'hover', sortableData[hoverIndex].name);
    }
    // todo - change the order in array
  },
  [sortableData],
);

<StyledTreeTable
  components={components}
  dataSource={sortableData}
  onRow={(record, index) => {
    return {
      index,
      moveRow: moveRow(record as StructureElement),
    };
  }}
/>
```

So the problem is, my `sortableData` looks like this:

```
[
  { name: 1 },
  { name: 2 },
  {
    name: 3,
    children: [
      { name: 11 },
      { name: 22 },
      { name: 33, children: [{ name: 111 }, { name: 222 }, { name: 333 }] },
    ],
  },
];
```

So my objects can have more objects nested in children.

But `moveRow` function doesn't see it this way. For it, `ABSTRACT_STATE_4` is of index `4`. So when I try to reorder the array, I try to do this: `data[4]`, which results in `undefined`.

Is there a way I can reorder the items in tree table with drag and drop, that I haven't found yet?

The only way I see of solving it now, is to recreate the array the way `hover` and `drag` indexes match. But that's a lot of seemingly unnecessary work.

Is there a way to get the record I am hovering over, like I'm getting `hoverIndex`?

Comment: Have you been able to do it? I also struggled some months ago and gave up..

Comment: Yes. I ended up using another library. https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd unfortunately I don't have access to the finished code, but this library worked

Comment: Wow! So with react-beautiful-dnd you were able to make a drag-n-drop antd tree table. Since you don't have access to the code, any advice or pitfall that you remember? Thanks in advance

Comment: It was as simple as making each draggable component both a draggable, and a dropzone. This way, you'll have both indexes during the `onDrop` call, and you can just switch them. You can also set the indexes to item ids. This was crucial in my case.

Comment: @GregForel if you get a sample working, please post it as an answer. I forgot to do it